# Grouby function to get string of a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I hava Dataframe `X` like this:

```
ID   Category
1      green
1      green
2      orange
2      orange
3      yellow
3      yellow
3      yellow
8      green
8      green
8      green
```

and I am trying to get a Dataframe `Category` like this:

```
ID   Category
1      green
2      orange
3      yellow
8      green
```

I tried with this groupby function but I doesn't get the result as expected:

```
Category = X.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False)['Category']
```

I guess the solution is damn easy, but i didn't find a solution for it, as it is a string.
Thanks

Comment: need `df = df.drop_duplicates('ID')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='first')
```

Output will be as follows.

```
   ID     Category
0  1       green 
2  2       orange 
4  3       yellow 
7  8       green
```